# Navigation stack monitoring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mapkit

Can anyone tell me why this comparison keeps making my app freeze and crash?

```
NSArray *viewControllerArray = [controlFromMap.navigationController viewControllers];
NSUInteger parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 3 // or - whatever;
NSLog(@"Parent view controller: %@", [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex]);



if([[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex]stringValue] isEqualToString: @"FromAddressController"]){

    _mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
}
else{

_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
```

Comment: i am trying to monitor the the navigation stack to determine what to display on a map and it. The NSLog outputs the controller's name and that is what i am trying to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex] should return an instance of UIViewController subclass. Make sure it responds to -stringValue or (assuming FromAddressController  is a class name) make it so:

```
if([[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex] class] == [FromAddressController class])
```

Comment: right, it does return that value, but from what i see it does not respond to the string value.

Answer (score 1):

If you add:

```
NSLog(@"parentViewControllerIndex: %d", parentViewControllerIndex);
```

after the line:

```
NSUInteger parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 3;
```

What value do you see in the console?

Comment: 73793360, that number shows up for that particular stack of controllers

Comment: You're using an `NSUInteger`, which is unsigned. A signed integer that is negative will be wrapped around when it is made unsigned and you'll get a large integer result, like what you see. What this means is that you are getting an out-of-bounds error on the `viewControllerArray` — you are trying to reference an element of this array that does not exist. Perhaps you shouldn't subtract 3 from your count, but something less.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this line:

```
if([[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex]stringValue] isEqualToString: @"FromAddressController"]){
```

looks suspicious to me.

I checked the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) and the `UIViewController` class does not appear to have a `-stringValue` method. So you probably will get an unrecognized selector exception and your application will crash.

Perhaps you mean `nibName` instead of `stringValue`?

Comment: well, i tried the nibName, but that one did not work cause they are in the same nib file. i guess i have to tlook at something else to compare

Comment: You can look into `class` as Costique suggested, but if you're trying to reference the 73793360th element of `viewControllerArray`, you will certainly run into an out-of-bounds exception that will crash your app, whether you use `class` or `nibName`, because you will not have 73793360+ view controllers on your navigation stack.

Comment: right i got u, thats a underflow issue. I'll look deeper into that class. thank you